# How to Deploy Project in Cross Account EC2 Instances Using CodePipeline in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline

I have four AWS account,

- Account A (For CodePipeline)
- Account B (For Development EC2 Instance)
  Now, I want to deploy my CodeBase into Account B EC2 Instance From Account A CodePipeline. How to can i do it,
  Note : I don't want to use CloudFormation.

I have no idea that how to make it possible.

Comment: You will need to integrate code deploy in the code pipeline and give permissions to code pipeline to assume code deploy roles in the other account check below one. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-cross-account.html